# Unity: Blend tree triggering and diagonal issue

Tags: unity

So I have some issues with directional animation using a blend tree that sometimes triggers other animation, it's an attack animation that has the direction control on it, for example, if a left stick up will trigger `attack up animation` if a left stick down will trigger `attack down animation` to do that im using blend tree and its working, but sometimes when I try to left stick to up its triggering `attack up animation` also `attack right or left animation` depend on where it's current player facing.

**This is what my animator looks like:**

[image]

so `Rod attack and Rod attack 0 blend tree`, and I have parameters XVelocity and YVelocity to set direction

**What RodAttack Looks like:**

[image]

**What RodAttack 0 Looks like:**

[image]

Why do I separate this I think because the `RodAttack 0` only triggers when the player is not on the ground so I have to, also on this I don't know why my diagonal animation won't trigger.

this is a script to control the animation:

```cs
void animation(){
.....
         if (isCana)
            {
                anim.SetBool("isCana", isCana);
                anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rb2D.velocity.x));

                if (isAttackRod)
                {
                    anim.SetBool("cañaAttack", isAttackRod);

                    anim.SetBool("isNotGround", false);
                    anim.SetFloat("XVelocity", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")));
                    anim.SetFloat("YVelocity", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")));

                    if (!isGrounded && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.3f)
                    {
                        anim.SetBool("isNotGround", true);
                        anim.SetFloat("XVelocity", (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")));
                        anim.SetFloat("YVelocity", (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")));

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool("cañaAttack", isAttackRod);
                    anim.SetBool("isNotGround", false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetBool("isCana", isCana);
                anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rb2D.velocity.x));
                anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
                anim.SetFloat("YVelocity", rb2D.velocity.y);

                if (!isGrounded)
                {
                    anim.SetBool("isGolpeSal", isgolpe);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool("Attackone", isgolpe);
                    anim.SetBool("AttackTwo", isgolpe2);
                    anim.SetBool("isGolpeSal", false);
                }
            }
..........
}
```

**The result is like this:**

[image]

as you can see it's triggering other animation, also when I jump it's my joystick diagonally positioned on `x=1` and `y=-1` but the diagonal animation not triggering.

I already tried to adjust values x and y values on the blend tree but still the same.

Comment: why are you using `2d`? for what you're trying to achieve, I recommend using the `1d` option (you don't get those floating warnings anymore too)

Comment: @ArianKeshvari  I using 2d because there is some diagonal animation so im using that, am I wrong?

Comment: I was talking about `RodAttack0`, not the other one. since the `Y` value is set to -1 in all of them, you may use `1d`